# Data on jcpenneys sales

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I'm looking for a source for prices on jcpenneys items from the years 2010-2015. This is to investigate their fair and square marketing disaster. However, I cannot find any catalogs online or any sort of way to map out prices through those 5 years.

Where can I get a data set for this?